# Symfony Twig {{render}} handling passed arguments

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-3.3

Over a template I do a `render` method:

```
{{ render(controller('AppBundle:Widgets:myCapsWidget'),{'somestring':someString})  }}
```

Over the controller I have the following method:

```
public function myCapsWidgetAction($somestring)
{
  return new Response(strtoupper($somestring));
}
```

I also looked over theese links:

- [symfony twig render controller argument array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36048191/symfony-twig-render-controller-argument-array)
- https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony2-ep3/render-controller

But still cannot find any light to my path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read the first link you gave us, you should use:

```
{{ render(controller('AppBundle:Widgets:myCapsWidget',{'somestring':someString}))  }}
```