# Symfony Twig {{render}} handling passed arguments: Cannot get a different value

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-3.3

Over a template I do a `render` method:

```
 {% set someString = "non-default" %}

{{ render(controller('AppBundle:Widgets:myCapsWidget'),{'somestring':someString})  }}
```

Over the controller I have the following method:

```
public function myCapsWidgetAction()
{
  //@todo: access the passing parameter
}
```

My problem is how can I access the `somestring` parameter? I tried to do

```
public function myCapsWidgetAction($somestring="default")
{
  return new Response(strtoupper($somestring));
}
```

Then via xdebug I noticed that the passed parameter was `default` instead of `non-default`.

I also looked over theese links:

- [symfony twig render controller argument array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36048191/symfony-twig-render-controller-argument-array)
- https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony2-ep3/render-controller

But still no light in my path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Symfony Twig {{render}} handling passed arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47094755/symfony-twig-render-handling-passed-arguments)

You should render the widget like:

```
{{ render(controller('AppBundle:Widgets:myCapsWidget',{'somestring':someString})  }}
```

Look on how the argument are being passed over the controller method